# Display link with search results

Tags: php, if-statement, search

I have a simple search form on my basic page

```
<form action="../options-search.php" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="query" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

On the ../options-search.php page I have the following code

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $user, $pass, $dbase);


    $query = $_GET['query']; 
    $min_length = 3;

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        $query = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $query);

        $raw_results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Options WHERE (`options` COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%".$query."%')" );

        if(mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 

            while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)){

                echo "<p>".$results['options']."</p>";
            }
        }
        else{ 
            echo "Nothing Found";
        }             
    }
    else{ 
    }
?>
```

It works perfectly, however, some of the options have links in the database (for more info on the subject). For another page (not relevant here, but I was trying to use that code) I used the following line of code:

```
$data[] = $row['thumb'] == 'Yes' ? ">> <a href=\"" . $row['link'] . "\"> $row[options]</a>" : ">> $row[options]"    ;
```

This works on that page, but I cannot seem to get it added to this part:

```
echo "<p>".$results['options']."</p>";
```

So basically, I want the code to figure out if there is a value named "Yes" in the field "thumb". If not, then it only needs to display the $results['options'], but if it is, it needs to add a link to it. 
(It is the same database.)

I tried the following, but it doesn't work. The page is displayed without any errors, but the link isn't there.

```
echo "<p>".$results['thumb'] == 'Yes' ? ">> <a href=\"" . $results['link'] . "\"> $results[options]</a>" : ">> $results[options]"."</p>";
```

I also tried if / else statements, but I kept getting errors.

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Edit:

Html output. I only deleted the header and footer code.

Here's the Html code. I only deleted the header and footer information.

```
<div id="content" class="site-content"><div class="container"><div class="inner-wrapper">        <div id="separator-title">



                                  </div><!-- #separator-title -->

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Dancing+Script|Yellowtail|Kaushan+Script|Lobster+Two:400,400italic,700,700italic|Satisfy|Courgette|Playball|Tangerine|Bad+Script|Sacramento|Calligraffitti|Niconne|Parisienne|Eagle+Lake|Metal+Mania|Risque|Uncial+Antiqua|Amita|Spirax|Nova+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">



<h3>Options</h3>
<div style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px;">
<p><span style="color: #5e2132; font-size: 60px; float:left; padding: 0.25em 0.05em 0.25em 0; line-height: 0.4em; font-family:Lobster Two;">V</span>iew all of the options here. ***Page info not done yet***</p>
</p>
</div>

<h3>Search Results</h3>

<div style='padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px;'>
<p><span style='color: #5e2132; font-size: 60px; float:left; padding: 0.25em 0.05em 0.25em 0; line-height: 0.4em; font-family:Lobster Two;'>T</span>he search rendered the following Results: <br><br>

>> Cats</p>
<div style='padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px;'><p><span style='color: #5e2132; font-size: 60px; float:left; padding: 0.25em 0.05em 0.25em 0; line-height: 0.4em; font-family:Lobster Two;'>I</span>f you want to search for something else or view the complete list again, use the following button:</p>
            <center><a style='border-radius: 8px; position: relative; background-image: linear-gradient(#fff,#834052b3); background-color: #fff; border: #5e2132 solid 2px; color: #5e2132; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5); box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px; margin: auto; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; margin-top: 10px;' href='../options/'>Back to Options</a></center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $results['thumb'] == 'Yes' ? "<p>>> <a href=\"" . $results['link'] . "\">" .  $results[options] . "</a></p>" : "<p>>> " . $results[options] ."</p>";
```

you have misplaced the string connectors and one paragraph closing tag

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but there's still no link. No errors, but also no link.

Comment: @Bar2aYunie just copy 1 or 2 lines of the echo statement.. I wanna see who it shows for data.. There is also a chance that you don't have anything in $results['thumb']

Comment: @Bar2aYunie i see it now.. try the new code i just edited my post

Comment: It gave me this error: Use of undefined constant options - assumed 'options'. So I added these: '

That solved it! Thank you very much!